# Nested class, undefined reference, static method

Tags: c++, class, static, nested

I have problem and no idea how to resolve it. I believe this is stupid trivial:

I have 3 files:
Util.hpp

```
class Util  
{  
    public:  
        class BitParser  
        {
            public:
                static bool getBitAt(int buf, int idx);  
        };  
};
```

Util.cpp

```
#include "Util.hpp"
bool Util::BitParser::getBitAt(int buf, int idx)
{
    return true;
}
```

application.cpp

```
#include "Util.hpp"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Util::BitParser::getBitAt(1,1);
}
```

Of couse, files listed above are in the same directory. And now when I try to link and compile I recieve linker error:

```
$ g++ -o app application.cpp
application.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `Util::BitParser::getBitAt(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is screwed up?

Comment: Add util.cpp to the compile command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told g++ to compile your 'main' program, but didn't tell it about the Util module.  Add `Util.cpp` to the command line and all should work well.

The compiler has brewn an "application.o" file that *refers* to the `Util::bitparser` functions.

The linker should 'link' these referrals to the "util.o" file, containing the actual code for these functions.  But it has no .o file containing a function satisfying the link.  That's what it calls "undefined reference": "application.o" *refers* to a function the linker doesn't find.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile (and link) all the `.cpp` files. So in your case, the command would be

```
$ g++ -o app application.cpp Util.cpp
```

Better still, write a Makefile to do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include both application.cpp and Util.cpp in the build.